# Logging Java output

Tags: java, powershell, logging

I want to log every output of a Java file started from PowerShell.
The Java code is inside a loop and looks as follows:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $propertyFilesDir) {
    & $javaExe -classpath "$classPath" com.tech.test.Export "$PropertyFilesDir\$file"
}
```

The first output of the loop is logged but all others are not.

I also tried it with `Start-Process` and redirecting the stdout and sterr.
Also calling `cmd /c "xxx"` did not work.

Comment: Side note: the objects `Get-ChildItem` produces have a property `FullName` with the full path to the file/folder. Replace `"$PropertyFilesDir\$file"` with `$file.FullName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-3.0) for directing output to a log file ([see also](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)).

PowerShell v3 or later:

```
& $javaExe ... *>> 'C:\your.log'
```

`>>` appends to a file. `*` merges all output streams into one.

PowerShell v2 or earlier:

```
& $javaExe ... >> 'C:\your.log' 2>&1
```

Prior to PowerShell v3 only the success and the error output stream could be redirected. Redirection of other streams was not supported. `2>&1` merges the error output stream with the success output stream, so that both normal and error output goes to the same file.

Of course you can also redirect each stream to an individual file (as far as redirection of the stream is supported):

```
& $javaExe ... >> 'C:\output.log' 2>> 'C:\error.log' [3>> 'C:\warning.log' ...]
```

---

Another option for logging everything from a console is the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet:

```
Start-Transcript -Path 'C:\your.log' -NoClobber
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $propertyFilesDir) {
    ...
}
Stop-Transcript
```

---

What does not work is redirecting the entire loop output:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $propertyFilesDir) {
    ...
} > 'C:\path\to\your.log' 2>&1
```

You'd need to use `ForEach-Object` instead of a `foreach` loop to be able to redirect output that way:

```
Get-ChildItem $propertyFilesDir | ForEach-Object {
    ...
} > 'C:\path\to\your.log' 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried everything but nothing got all the output I wanted from the loop.
But maybe it's because of PS Version 2 we use. 
Is there another way for PS v2?

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is running the PowerShell script from CMD and redirecting the output of that process: `powershell.exe -File "your.ps1" > "your.log" 2>&1`